# Use Javascript Libary On Typescript Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, typescript-typings

I want to use an payment system which is calling iyzico.
The iyzico payment library is https://www.npmjs.com/package/iyzipay it. But there is not any types so how can i use this library on my node.js typescript express backend project?

i tried make one mylib.d.ts file on my root directory and put this code on this file.

```
declare module 'iyzipay';
```

After then i put this variable on my tsconfig.json file

```
  ,"include": [
    "src", "mylib.d.ts"
  ]
```

When i import the libary on my project i get an error like this.

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'iyzipay'. '/Users/xxx/node_modules/iyzipay/lib/Iyzipay.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/iyzipay` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'iyzipay';

Comment: Have you looked at <https://www.npmjs.com/package/iyzipay-ts>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare export types for module 'iyzipay';

For example:

```js
declare module 'iyzipay' {

  interface IyzipayOptions {
    apiKey: string;
    secretKey: string;
    uri: string;
  }

  class Iyzipay {
    constructor (options: IyzipayOptions);
  }
  
  export default Iyzipay;
}
```

This type declaring is just for the simple usage from [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iyzipay#initialization). You should write the types as you need.

```js
import Iyzipay from 'iyzipay';

var iyzipay = new Iyzipay({
    apiKey: 'your api key',
    secretKey: 'your secret key',
    uri: 'https://sandbox-api.iyzipay.com'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're facing issues with type definitions for the iyzipay library in your TypeScript project, I've published TypeScript definitions for iyzipay under **@types/iyzipay**. You can easily include these in your project to get proper type support. Here's how you can do it:

## Install the Type Definitions

First, you need to add these type definitions to your project. Run the following command in your project directory:

```bash
npm install --save-dev @types/iyzipay
```

Or, if you're using Yarn, use this command instead:

```bash
yarn add --dev @types/iyzipay
```

## Use iyzipay in Your TypeScript Code

With the type definitions installed, TypeScript should automatically recognize the types when you import and use iyzipay. For example:

```js
import Iyzipay from 'iyzipay';

const iyzipay = new Iyzipay({
  apiKey: 'your_api_key',
  secretKey: 'your_secret_key',
  uri: 'https://sandbox-api.iyzipay.com'
});

// Now, you can use iyzipay with full TypeScript support.
```

## Check Your tsconfig.json

Ensure your tsconfig.json file is correctly set up to include type definitions from the node_modules/@types directory. This is usually the default behavior, so you shouldn't have to change anything unless you have a custom setup.

---

By following these steps, you should be able to use iyzipay in your TypeScript project with full type support, making your development process smoother and helping you avoid type-related errors.

If you encounter any issues with the type definitions or have suggestions for improvements, feel free to contribute to the @types/iyzipay package or reach out for further assistance.